# Split a regular expression string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a regular expression defined as [a-zA-Z_0-9]{1,29} in a string and I want to extract only [a-zA-Z_0-9] out of it and I'm using the below code to do it. But console.log returns me ["[a-zA-Z_", "-9]{1,29}"] as the output. Where am I going wrong ?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.val = "";
  $scope.regEx = "[a-zA-Z_0-9]{1,29}";
  $scope.pattern = $scope.regEx.split(0,12);
  console.log($scope.pattern) //it should return [a-zA-Z_0-9]
});
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/PFLZXs6er2lG3ieG4mi8?p=preview

Comment: `split` breaks the string into an array of strings based on an input character or string. For example, `string.split('{');` What you are looking for is `substr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'standard' way to use split is something like this:

```
$scope.val = "abc;def;ghi";
$scope.regEx = /\s*;\s*/;
$scope.list = $scope.val.split($scope.regEx);
console.info($scope.list);
```

with the result:

```
["abc", "def", "ghi"]
```

As said, you're probably looking for substr()...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `substr`

`$scope.pattern = $scope.regEx.substr(0,12);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.pattern = $scope.regEx.substr(0,12);
```